# Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?

Tags: html, css

I have to fit an iframe in screen height. Obviously, I wanted 100% as in width but, since that doesn't work, I used 100vh.
But vh like  vw is not exactly 100%.
In my laptop through chrome while the 100% width renders perfectly without the need for a horizontal scroll bar, vw has about a centimeter extra.

Comment: FYI, as for height, `100vh` > `100%` in some mobile browsers, which once troubled me.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

vw and vh stand for viewport width and viewport height respectively.

The difference between using `width: 100vw` instead of `width: 100%` is that while `100%` will make the element fit all the space available, the viewport width has a specific measure, in this case the width of the available screen, including the document margin.

If you set the style `body { margin: 0 }`, 100vw should behave the same as 100% (for an element that is a child to `body`).

#### Additional notes

Using `vw` as unit for everything in your website, including font sizes and heights, will make it so that the site is always displayed proportionally to the device's screen width regardless of it's resolution. This makes it super easy to ensure your website is displayed exactly the same in both workstation and mobile.

You can set `font-size: 1vw` (or whatever size suits your project) in your `body` CSS and everything specified in `rem` units will automatically scale according to the device screen, so it's easy to port existing projects and even frameworks (such as Bootstrap that already uses `rem` as unit for everything) to this concept.

Comment: Also note thet width: 100% is relative to it's first parent with a layout. So if you have an element with width:100% inside another element that has a specific width, the child element will only take up the total width of that parent.

Comment: I just noticed that setting an element to be `100vw` can cause a horizontal scrollbar to appear when a vertical scrollbar is visible. According to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), only Firefox exhibits correct behavior by subtracting the scrollbar width from `100vw`. For every other browser, you will need to use `100%` instead.

Comment: This is (now?) incorrect. The [current editor draft docs state](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) that viewport lengths must ignore scrollbars and [MDN additionally documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) that this is only with overflow: auto; if overflow is set to scroll (with scrollbars always visible) then viewport lengths do respect them (didn't see it in the draft myself). 100% references the parent element not the viewport, and as such does not ignore scrollbars in any case.

Comment: As far as I can see the differentiation on margins is incorrect. When I set a child to 100% width or 100vw width and add and remove a margin from the body they behave the same way.

Comment: "100vw should behave the same as 100%.", not if there is a scroll bar to the right.

Answer (score 60):

Havenard's answer doesn't seem to be strictly true. I've found that vw fills the viewport width, but doesn't account for the scrollbars. So, if your content is taller than the viewport (so that your site has a vertical scrollbar), then using vw results in a small horizontal scrollbar. I had to switch out `width: 100vw` for `width: 100%` to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this issue be adding `max-width`:

```
#element {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vw;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

When you using CSS to make the wrapper full width using the code `width: 100vw;` then you will notice a horizontal scroll in the page, and that happened because the `padding` and `margin` of `html` and `body` tags added to the wrapper size, so the solution is to add `max-width: 100%`

Comment: Can you describe said issue please?

Comment: When you using CSS to make the wrapper full width using the code ``` width: 100vw;``` then you will notice a horizontal scroll in the page, and that happened because padding and margin of ```html``` and ```body``` tags added to the wrapper size, so the solution to add  ```max-width: 100%```

Answer (score 3):

[@Havenard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw/25225716#25225716) provides the perfect explanation for the question. Adding to that, this provides a visual representation of the difference.

You'll be able to notice the key difference between `100vw` and `100%` when you have a site with scrollbars and an element that is supposed to fit the entire width of the screen.

### Option 1

Below is an example of the same. 
All i'm doing in the code below is changing the width of `<h1>` tag from `100vw` to `100%` when you hover over it.

```css
body {
  /* margin: 0; */
}

.scroll {
  height: calc(110vh);
}

h1 {
  width: 100vw;
  /* width: 100%;*/
  text-align: right;
  outline: 5px solid black
}

h1:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

h1:before {
float: left;
  content: "100vw "
}

h1:hover:before {
  content: "100% "
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <p>Hover over the below block</p>
  <h1>Width</h1>
</div>
```

If you run the above code snippet and hover the text, you'll notice 2 things:

1. the horizontal scrollar disappears
2. the entire text will be visible
   to you

*Note: after running the above snippet, you can play around with above code in browser devtools to see how it affects the elements*

---

### Option 2 (*Chrome and Edge*)

```css
.scroll{
height: calc(110vh);
display: flex;
align-items: baseline;
}

h1{
width: 100vw;
/* width: 100%; */
text-align:right;
outline: 10px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
```

Another way to visually see the difference in your own project is by setting a `display:flex` style to an element with 100vw.

When you highlight this elements in browser devtools, You can notice the a leftward point arrow at the right end of the element. Also you can see than the shading of the highlighted elements spans across the scroll-bar, indicating that it is considering the entire screen-width (including scroll-bar width)

[image: 100vw vs 100% visual difference]

---

Other questions, that address similar issue are:

1. [100vw causing horizontal overflow, but only if more than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [CSS Units - What is the difference between vh/vw and %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Prevent 100vw from creating horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489594/prevent-100vw-from-creating-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  /* margin: 0; */
}

.scroll {
  height: calc(110vh);
}

h1 {
  width: 100vw;
  /* width: 100%;*/
  text-align: right;
  outline: 5px solid black
}

h1:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

h1:before {
float: left;
  content: "100vw "
}

h1:hover:before {
  content: "100% "
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <p>Hover over the below block</p>
  <h1>Width</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.