# Styling HTML and BODY selector to height: 100%; vs using 100vh

Tags: css, html

My brother and I were messing around in sublime earlier and he suddenly shout out, "I learned something new!"

A little shocked, I asked, "What's that..?"

He replied, "Viewport height! I started in I.E.6 when it wasn't fully supported and never really looked at it again." He then proceeded to show me.

To which I replied, "I accomplished the same thing here." and showed him another sandbox project I messed around with.

In my project, in the CSS, I wrote

(edit: I edited to put the background color in the div, not the html or body, my mistake)

(jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nvLq8eg9/embedded/result/ )

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

his code is,
(jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nvLq8eg9/1/embedded/result/ )

```
div {
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
}
```

Both did virtually the same thing. After doing some research on here, it appears as if the commonly run in to issue via the former method is the inability to scroll; however, on my sandbox project I had more content in it and was able to scroll and interact with the website normally.

Neither of us were able to determine what the differences were between both methods. Would anyone on here be able to educate us?

Thank you!

Comment: One big advantage of the latter: A height in percentage needs a height set on the parent element as well, whereas `vh` doesn’t, so you can use it “everywhere”, even further down the line within a parent element that doesn’t have a height set or has different height.

Comment: @Medri:  Did you see this article?  http://www.weareconvoy.com/2014/07/css-vw-and-vh-units-are-they-worth-using-yet/

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! We definitely overlooked that. I personally assumed that since the document's HTML and BODY elements would be the primary parents, with their height already set to 100%, it wouldn't matter for any new elements added. It seems as if vh allows for more specific styling instead of a universal catch all.

Comment: @Grafica I did not, but I am reading it now!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`height: 100vh` = 100% of the viewport height

`height: 100%` = 100% of the parent's element height

That is why you need to add `height: 100%` on `html` and `body`, as they don't have a size by default

Something you have to know : if you use % for vertical margin or padding, % will be calculated on the **width** of the parent element, not the height.

Tip : try using vh and vw units for font size :) I like this one (not supported in some browsers I know) : `font-size: calc(.5vh + .5vw);` (for example)

See a nice page here for CSS units : http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/

Comment: Did you mean "That is why you need to add `height: 100vh` on `html` and `body`"? Otherwise it seems to me that it is 100% of an undefined number.

Comment: @NickThompson no I meant 100%. I'm trying to find out why, but html knows where to find the value. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Comment: That line making the font size depending on both the vw and vh is really helpful

Comment: Though the answer provides information on the difference of definition, but I think the "right answer" should provide information on the practical difference, i.e is there something I can do with one that I can't with the other, edge cases difference etc.

Comment: I read somewhere that `100vh` has problems on mobile devices. Apparently it ignores the address bar in mobile browsers.

Comment: @J86 Yes, you're right. Took me forever to realize what was the root of my issues on mobile browsers. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Comment: This answer deserves more points!

Comment: Little late, but today mobile bar can be solved with the svh (SmallViewHeight)

Comment: @Medda86 thx for the head up, that's quite interesting indeed - https://css-tricks.com/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/

edit: omg https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/ (2018 situation)

Answer (score 10):

It's also worth noting that mobile toolbars are NOT included in the viewport height. Apparently this is by design. ([CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)) This makes vh and vw frustrating to use for mobile. The worst is when your modal's `X` button is covered by a mobile toolbar.

You can come across similar problems with scrollbars and body margin/padding in `vw`. ([Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw))

If you need something to take up the whole viewport height, consider using `height:100%` (and making sure to set `height:100%` on both the html and body tags). It is a huge pain as described above, however, if you end up needing to specify `height:100%` on a long nested chain of elements.

If you don't have a lot of nested elements, using `height:100%` seems like the way to go. Otherwise, with a lot of nested elements, `vh` saves you the trouble.

If mobile toolbars are still a relevant problem, then you may need to actively calculate with `window.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 6):

View port units = **vw, vh, vmin, and vmax** - are based on the size of the browser viewport.
Because, their actual size changes depending on the Viewport Size, this makes them great units for responsive design

> **Note:** When dealing with widths, the **%** unit is more suitable but with heights, the **vh** unit is better.
>
> the width of the viewport will actually be larger than the width of the html element.
>
> Viewport > html > body

Answer (score 5):

> height: 100vh = 100% of the viewport height

Technically, this is true, but a better way to think of it is = 100% of the available height.

If you are looking to fill up a div with the available height, that's a mighty useful trick.  Before I learned this, I would have to ensure every div from html down to the nested div had a height of 100% which can be tedious and error prone. Instead, I now just use height:100vh on the nested item.

See this gist.run for an [example](https://gist.run/?id=293fbfbee79eefd3d1351458d8d849c3) with Bootstrap 4.1:

Comment: This isn't correct. If you stack two divs each with a class that provides 100vh. you'll end up with a page that has a scroll bar, where the lower div is equal to the entire viewport height. https://jsfiddle.net/mikechabot/L3px491b/

Comment: Your example is correct.  The point I am trying to make is that 100vh is 100% of the available height.  So you your sample, you stack two of these, so the top one fills the available height, and then the bottom one duplicates this same height.  So you get a vertical scroll bar to fit both of them.

Answer (score 2):

This is also interesting:

Here, blue color is for `<body>` and red is for `<html>`. If you use `100vh`, and then the browser is resized so the content is not visible fully - you get scrollbar. When you scroll, `<body>` that was `100vh`, will stay above and you will see red part of the `<html>`.

When using `100%`, you get `<body>` covering `<html>` all the time.

[image]