# Hamburger menu 100% height

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm making a responsive hamburger menu for a test app. I want the hamburger menu to occupy the entire screen (100% of the height) when it's opened.

I tried media queries: `.header .menu` height to 100% but it doesn't work:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #8C2635;
}

a:hover {
  color: #8B8D33;
}


/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 30px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">OBJETIVOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">PARCEIROS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACTOS</a></li>
  </ul>

</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

For class `.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu` I set the `height` to `100vh`, and also the `max-height` since it was only `300px`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #8C2635;
}

a:hover {
  color: #8B8D33;
}


/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 30px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">OBJETIVOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">PARCEIROS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACTOS</a></li>
  </ul>

</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `height: 100vh` = 100% of the viewport height
>
> `height: 100%` = 100% of the parent's element height
>
> Something you have to know : if you use % for vertical margin or
>   padding, % will be calculated on the **width** of the parent element,
>   not the height.
>
> See a nice page here for CSS units:
>   http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/

Copied from [Styling HTML and BODY selector to height: 100%; vs using 100vh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804632/7910454)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [calc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) in this case:

```
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 80px); 
}
```