# How to use CSS grid layout for footer on mobile device

Tags: android, css

I've recently started using CSS grid layout for a web application. I found a nice example at https://duwp7.csb.app/ that does what I want when on a desktop browser. I really like that I don't need to use javascript to pad the main content to make room for the header and footer.

However when I use a mobile browser I find that the footer is below the bottom of the screen and I need to scroll to get to it. Is it possible to use a CSS grid layout footer on a mobile device? Or do I need to stick with my CSS + javascript solution?

The CSS that I'm using is below. "fll-sw-ui-body" is used for the container element.

```
.fll-sw-ui-body {
    /* make sure that only the content scrolls */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* use full viewport for elements, also avoids pushing elements off the screen when using full height */
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
}

.fll-sw-ui-body>header, .fll-sw-ui-body>footer {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eee;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.fll-sw-ui-body>header {
    grid-area: header;
}

.fll-sw-ui-body>main {
    grid-area: main;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.fll-sw-ui-body>footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

HTML code

```
<body class='fll-sw-ui-body'>
    <header>
        header content ...
    </header>
    <main>
        main content ...
    </main>
    <footer>
        footer content ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your css code look like?

Comment: I've added my css and example HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out when while reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749468/2965897. The key is to use 100% instead of 100vh for the main container AND make sure to set the height of all parent elements to 100% as well. The working example is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
<style>
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

header, footer, main {
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-area: header;
}

footer {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    grid-area: footer;
}

main {
    overflow: auto;
    grid-area: main;
}
</style>

</head>

<body translate="no">

  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main
          <div>Top line</div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            Text here.
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>
            More....
          </div>
          <div>Bottom line</div>

  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example given doesn't really show how should the `footer` be placed correctly. The example is putting `footer` inside of `main`.

For me I usually put `header`, `main` and `footer` under `body` with the same level.

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

So that you can style the layout in css grid. We're pushing the `footer` to the bottom by growing `main`.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

**TL;DR**

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/BarJOGe

---

**EDIT**

> I tried your example and the issue I have with it is that the footer
> isn't fixed at the bottom. When I add more content to main so that it
> overflows the footer isn't visible until one scrolls to it.

So I guess you want a footer always on the bottom of the screen and it will always be visible.

If you want to get rid of scrolling among `body`, you will then have to set the `body`'s height to `100vh` and make `main` the actual scrollable area.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto; //or 'scroll'
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/zYWRrao)

Comment: I fixed the link to the example app. I'm working from the article https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-css-grid-for-sticky-headers-and-footers/ and meant to post the first example https://duwp7.csb.app/ not the second one with footer inside of main.

Comment: I tried your example and the issue I have with it is that the footer isn't fixed at the bottom. When I add more content to main so that it overflows the footer isn't visible until one scrolls to it.

Comment: So you actually want a `footer` which is always stick to the bottom of the screen and is always visible?

Comment: OK, I tried that at https://mtu.net/~jpschewe/temp/grid-03.html, but that didn't appear to put the footer at the bottom, what am I missing? The one at https://mtu.net/~jpschewe/temp/grid-02.html works in a desktop browser, but doesn't work on mobile.