# HTML Div doesnt fit

Tags: html

So my current div doesn't fit the webpage.. Both width and height is set to 100% and no padding is active..
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/syq2U.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style4.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   <div class=Topbar>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Topbar{ 
height:5vh;
width:100vw;
background-color:red;
padding:-3;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Comment: _"and no padding is active"_ - most certainly padding and/or margin on the html and/or body elements are "active", applied via the browser stylesheet. You need to explicitly set them to 0.

Comment: @CBroe is right. Just set `margin: 0`on your body.

Comment: have a look previous answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25225716/4426282

Answer (score 2):

Use the following style to remove the space.

body{
`margin:0;`
}

Answer (score -3):

Web pages default leave a space on the right

Comment: How does this help the OP?