# Viewport not working when body is set as 1020px

Tags: html, css, viewport

I am trying to make the top border of the nav div to cover the entire screen but it is not working.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1; 
  width: 1020px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.nav {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  border-top: 6px solid #9FCC7F; 
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav"></div><!-- Nav --> 
</body>
```

It is strange that the view port function is not working? Would you mind taking a look?

[image]

thanks again.

Comment: kindly clarify what is your expectation?

Comment: remove `width: 1020px` from body solves it?

Comment: this is what I am trying to achieve - http://i.imgur.com/pXdXMYr.png

@prasad

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is - trying to set the width to 1020px or 980px and then occasionally use 100vw in some divs to cover the entire screen

Answer (score 0):

change the width: 100vw to width 100% and it should work

Take a look at this: [Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.nav {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  border-top: 6px solid #9FCC7F;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="nav"></div><!-- Nav --> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because, the body width 1020px you mentioned exceeds the resolution that a device can support,

Check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

So viewport cannot render correctly when the fixed width exceeds maximum resolution of the device

Set the property as

```
body{
 width:100%; // for full page width
}
```

else

leave the width, the browser automatically detects it

Answer (score 0):

Removing width:1020px from body solves your problem.

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/rahulxdd/wc5c0xk1/

```
    body {
          width: 100%;
         }
```

Comment: Add more clarification, what is the issue and display it using fiddle.

Comment: i don;t want to remove 1020px

Answer (score 0):

I added the code for You :
 better you apply with `width:100%` because its will auto adjust with in responsive view port. `px` are not adapting

`1020px` only adapting with in desktop mode.switch with `mobile,tab` mode its not usefull.so only sugges with `100%`

And don't forget to add viewport tag 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
Its a auto adjust with viewport .

[See Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  }

.nav {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-top: 6px solid #9FCC7F; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav"></div><!-- Nav --> 
</body>
```