# body is not covering full page

Tags: html, css

What can I do to make the body cover the whole page? In my CSS for body and html height and width 100%.

With the mobile version, the body is reduced in this way
[image: mobile]

With the pc version, everything is fine with the width, but the height is not on the whole page
[image: pc]

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}
```

[Here is my full html and css](https://jsfiddle.net/Skorz1/am61dLr9/3/)

and if you can tell me what else can be corrected, I will be very grateful

Comment: use: `height: 100vw` Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many of your elements have fixed width in px, which doesn't change in the media query. E.g. you have:

```
.container {
    width: 890px;
    ...
}

.menu__list {
  ...
  width: 700px;
}
```

You need to change them in your media query

`@media screen and (max-width: 450px) { ... }`

Personallly I'd keep only the container width in px for desktop and other things in percents, then in mobile versions I'd keepp them all in percents like

```
.container {
  width: 100%
}
```

Or sometimes

```
.container {
  width: 100%
  max-width: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basing on the first code you posted.**

Modify your container class css (Desktop) since its inheriting from wrapper.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

Your current css ( remove width & padding )

```
.container {
    width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Mobile is fine, its just inheriting the screen size of the emulator.