# How do I correctly invalidate a timeline on refresh in gsap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm trying to implement a horizontally scrolling section using gsap. On resize however, the timeline gets messed up. It's especially visible on the end of the horizontal section, where the amount of white space gets bigger or the site gets cut off (depending on wether you're making the window wider or thinner). [`invalidateOnRefresh: true`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) is supposed to fix this and recalculate the timeline values on refresh, but it has no effect in my example. How do I implement it correctly?

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const tl = gsap.timeline();

var sectionWidth = $(".section").width();

const ST = ScrollTrigger.create({
  animation: tl,
  trigger: ".container",
  start: 0,
  end: sectionWidth * 4,
  scrub: true,
  invalidateOnRefresh: true,
  pin: true,
});


tl.to(".container", 5, {
    x: -sectionWidth
  })
  .to(".container", 5, {
    x: -sectionWidth * 2
  })
  .to(".container", 5, {
    x: -sectionWidth * 3
  })
  .to(".container", 5, {
    x: -sectionWidth * 4
  });
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  width: 500vw;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.1/ScrollTrigger.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have added a simple demo similar to yours here: https://codepen.io/PhanDangKhoa96/pen/qByzezd

Two points to note:

- use % unit instead of vw for the width, you can read the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw)
- should use a callback function for `end: () => sectionWidth * 4`

I also simplify the `tl`

```
tl.to(sections, {xPercent: -100 * (sections.length -1)})
```

Comment: Wow I did not expect anybody to help me out here after all this time. Thank you! Could you explain what the callback for end specifically does?