# The width does not fit the screen, white space CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I'm editing my css and HTML but a bit bummed as the screen doesn't fit as I wish. I can slide it to the right but that's not what I want.

Any idea why this happens?

Here is the Header.js file created with React.js

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'

function Header() {

  const myStyle = {
    padding:0,
    marginBottom:-5
  }

  return (
    <div className="header">
        <div className="hidden">Example - Online Marketing Agency</div>
        <header id='home'>
            <h1 className='animate__animated animate__lightSpeedInRight'>Example</h1>
            {/* <div className="scroll-down"></div> */}
        </header>
        <svg className='animate__animated animate__fadeInUp' style={myStyle} viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L48,272C96,256,192,224,288,197.3C384,171,480,149,576,165.3C672,181,768,235,864,250.7C960,267,1056,245,1152,250.7C1248,256,1344,288,1392,304L1440,320L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Here on the Header.css you can see that i'm adding the color
a hidden class to hide element.

Header.css

```
.header {
    background: #6600ff;
}

.hidden {
    font-size: 0;
}

header {
    margin: 5.5vw;
    padding: 5.5vw;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 4vw;
    margin-bottom: -4vw;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.animate__fadeInUp {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.scroll-down {
    top: 200%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scroll-down::before,
.scroll-down::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    border-top: transparent;
    border-left: transparent;
    animation: scroll-down 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.scroll-down::after {
    top: 30%;
}

@keyframes scroll-down {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: 90%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 415px) {
    header {
        margin: 12vw;
        padding: 12vw;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 5.5vw;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    header h1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think anyone could help you without knowing what you did in the html and css code ... so post it here.

Comment: Use width 100vw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: It worked if I put this on the 
@media (max-width: 415px) { 
header {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
}

Thanks you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is nothing related to width
Add width: 100vw to .header and 100% to header

and you could read these resources
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp
[Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw)

Comment: a broad answer that might not even apply here. Block level elements by default will span the entire available width. So you not adding anything that isn't done by default.