# Prevent 100vw from creating horizontal scroll in pseudo

Tags: css, width, scrollbar, viewport

some times in wrapped by width div needs to set for an element background to full width, so I set it in an pseudo element, but descktop browser, when page is long height adds 16px for vertical scrooll bar to viewport, so I calculate it
by calc (see below).

Here is [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/swed/s12baLLo/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapped">
 <h1>100vw background in wrapped</h1>
 <div class="fullbg">
  some body text, images, etc here
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {    margin: 0;      padding: 0;    }
body {     height: 100%;     width: 100%;    }
div {      position: relative;   }
*,*:before,*:after {      box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapped {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 150vh; /* simulate long heigh */
}
.fullbg {
 height: 5em;
/* some styles here*/
}

.fullbg:before {
 content: "";
 bottom: 0;
 display: block;
 background: rgba(85, 144, 169, 0.7);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100vw;
 right: 50%;
 margin-right: -50vw;                /* work for short page or mobile browser*/
 margin-right: calc( -50vw + 8px );  /* work for desctop long page  */ 
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

I looked answer at

- [Prevent 100vw from creating horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489594/prevent-100vw-from-creating-horizontal-scroll)
- [Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225682/difference-between-width100-and-width100vw)

and others questions, 
but do not find real true universal css solution for this

as a temporary solution may be an js, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744352/5447232):

```
var scrollbarWidth = ($(document).width() - window.innerWidth);
```

but I think it not the best solution, and now I not figured out how to use it with a pseudo considering that to scroll width can vary.

ps. no one overflow: hidden!

Comment: Good question. I thought the "cssfix" fixed things by making the width allow for the width of the vertical scrollbar, but of course 8px wouldn't be enough to make that happen! Let's see what answers you get.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar can be targeted specifically.

Check this out for the fix in chrome and safari

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXgmbZ

Key CSS:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
width: 0 !important;
}`
```

The codepen is just your example with the chrome fix. If you'd like to see a more robust solution, check out this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/E78q3/

The idea behind this is just clipping out the scroll bar with `absolute` positioning and hiding container/wrapper `overflow`. Simple, clever, yet effective.

Further Reading:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/

Comment: It do not work in other browsers, And  need to keep stabdart scrolling.