# Flex Grow (Column) exceeds Horizontal Width

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky-footer

https://jsfiddle.net/p7e9vzu5/

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
    flex: 0;
}

main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
    flex: 0;
}
```

Whenever a third element is introduced within the body, with a vertical layout, a horizontal scrollbar is added.  If the third element is removed, case in point, the footer, the layout functions properly. I'm attempting to create a sticky footer using flexbox.

Browsers:

- Chrome 57.0.2987.37
- Chrome 58.0.3009.0
- Firefox 51.0.1

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: Don't use `width:100vw` on the footer.

Comment: If you have vertical scrollbar then 100vw is `width of window + width of scrollbar`, see these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489594/prevent-100vw-from-creating-horizontal-scroll/30504010#30504010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `width: 100vw;` property in the footer. When I removed it the scroll bar was removed.

```
footer {
    padding: 25px 10px;
    text-align: right;
    background: deeppink;
    flex: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 background: var(--background-colour);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
 flex: 0;
  background: deepskyblue;
  padding: 25px 10px;
}

main {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
 padding: 25px 10px;
 text-align: right;
 background: deeppink;
 flex: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla viverra aliquam massa, a faucibus velit egestas vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut mauris at nisl ullamcorper rutrum quis eu ipsum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse accumsan nulla sit amet nunc venenatis luctus. Vestibulum vestibulum eros velit, vel fermentum dolor scelerisque et. Proin dictum odio ante, eleifend auctor risus suscipit sit amet. Morbi at odio nec ligula placerat sodales ut eu nibh. Aenean ornare velit vitae nulla bibendum condimentum. Quisque porta et arcu ut gravida. Aenean sed lectus non orci convallis consectetur. Donec eget odio et leo dapibus vehicula. Morbi cursus lectus nec sem sagittis laoreet. Etiam fringilla lorem magna, nec blandit lorem malesuada condimentum. Etiam at ligula ac dui aliquam finibus vitae in ex. Sed feugiat aliquam nulla sagittis hendrerit. Nam et mauris justo. Proin volutpat ut nunc ut venenatis. Aliquam sagittis quam at purus fringilla sollicitudin. Integer condimentum venenatis quam, vitae congue justo viverra at. Praesent consequat porttitor justo, quis molestie ante ullamcorper vitae. Cras sit amet facilisis est. Morbi ut arcu quam. Duis vehicula nisl nec magna dignissim condimentum. Morbi scelerisque iaculis nisi ut sollicitudin. Sed vehicula erat lectus, vitae consequat est facilisis in. Suspendisse suscipit nec urna et posuere. Donec et ultricies turpis, vel volutpat sapien. Praesent hendrerit sit amet velit in fringilla. Suspendisse sollicitudin mi molestie libero lobortis condimentum. Phasellus dictum velit nec leo convallis, eu feugiat urna venenatis. Ut facilisis, ligula vel convallis varius, turpis neque pretium ante, eget hendrerit tortor magna in lacus. Nam velit dolor, iaculis vitae felis non, egestas porttitor lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam hendrerit, ante at accumsan commodo, sem odio pharetra arcu, vitae ultrices enim ante eu nunc. Sed at lectus placerat, tincidunt ante non, volutpat arcu. Pellentesque ultrices, tellus in dictum finibus, lacus justo vehicula lacus, in lobortis nunc libero rutrum nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur facilisis facilisis tellus sed mattis. Suspendisse pharetra vitae purus porttitor congue. Cras lobortis nisl at urna mattis mattis. Vivamus sagittis pharetra libero sed sollicitudin. Mauris consectetur tempor leo, sit amet sagittis ligula blandit et. Ut sit amet gravida risus. Nullam mauris enim, ornare vel quam vel, molestie viverra leo. Maecenas condimentum nec tellus quis iaculis. Mauris eros dui, efficitur non erat nec, convallis tristique elit. Phasellus sodales est ac purus blandit tristique. Sed aliquam est egestas, consequat nunc at, finibus mi. Nullam euismod diam magna, ac imperdiet mauris iaculis sed. Aenean porta eros nisi, ut mollis dui imperdiet ut. In vulputate sem dignissim consectetur pellentesque. Pellentesque lacinia magna venenatis ligula pulvinar, ac placerat lectus dignissim. Sed eget condimentum nulla, sed scelerisque erat. In tempor, lacus ut tempus bibendum, ligula augue mattis urna, sit amet lacinia ex arcu nec arcu. Pellentesque faucibus varius dolor eu pretium. Nam sit amet nisi ultricies, eleifend metus in, pretium enim. Praesent ac diam sed ante interdum tempor quis non eros. Maecenas mattis libero id lorem sollicitudin porttitor. Duis ac purus non risus interdum pretium ut id erat. Aliquam vel mi sit amet ligula pretium hendrerit. Donec ut urna magna. Phasellus mi eros, aliquam sit amet tincidunt et, egestas id velit. Donec bibendum leo blandit, commodo lorem a, tincidunt magna. Praesent fringilla aliquam ultricies. Aenean et lacus sapien. Ut sit amet semper magna. Aenean tristique ex eget elementum iaculis. Fusce condimentum malesuada mauris at cursus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum id quam tellus. Morbi egestas velit a orci auctor faucibus. Etiam dapibus ligula varius tempor ultricies. Quisque pretium ullamcorper nibh sed pharetra. Proin fringilla odio et tristique molestie. Nam et lorem cursus, egestas nisl ac, dignissim justo. Duis metus mauris, bibendum nec sem et, ultrices venenatis lorem. In congue metus auctor augue pellentesque, id tempor augue congue. Nam arcu sem, varius ac rutrum nec, sodales in lectus. Aenean dictum orci nibh, quis iaculis massa gravida non. Sed euismod magna id viverra ultrices. Vivamus fermentum ligula sed mauris convallis, eu ornare eros dictum. Etiam in nunc ac metus faucibus finibus. Duis vehicula augue sit amet lacinia posuere. Donec accumsan egestas iaculis. Quisque gravida, metus non faucibus cursus, mi odio luctus nisi, id gravida diam quam ac enim. Nullam malesuada purus lacinia ultrices ultricies. Sed rhoncus sapien id lectus feugiat, sit amet sollicitudin libero dictum. Donec consectetur consectetur sodales. Pellentesque facilisis dui et nisi pretium, at dapibus mi malesuada. Cras cursus sem eu nisi ornare, in mattis nibh euismod. Proin ut tristique orci. Duis viverra mauris neque, in ullamcorper risus pulvinar et. Etiam sagittis, sapien id tincidunt euismod, nibh nisi sagittis nisl, ac pharetra diam tellus nec lectus. Integer sagittis euismod placerat. Quisque lobortis condimentum ipsum et auctor. Aenean sit amet massa lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dolor massa, feugiat eu nisl id, convallis mollis urna. Ut non felis in metus gravida finibus. Sed turpis lacus, bibendum luctus condimentum ac, porta a ex. Nunc porta auctor nisi id eleifend. Duis et arcu iaculis, cursus mauris sit amet, porttitor turpis. Nunc eleifend fermentum libero, ac pharetra ex sodales quis. Etiam cursus, dui ac dignissim varius, massa urna fermentum lorem, et volutpat turpis lacus id lectus. Aliquam faucibus tempus metus. Vivamus convallis aliquet aliquet. Suspendisse malesuada massa ac justo hendrerit efficitur. Quisque quis luctus ex, sit amet rhoncus massa. Etiam iaculis massa et risus facilisis, egestas vehicula lacus tempus. Sed bibendum nisl in velit varius tempus. Curabitur fermentum, nunc quis porta euismod, diam purus convallis quam, non tempus massa arcu id purus. Fusce vel eleifend lectus. Phasellus auctor odio at ultrices volutpat. Morbi tristique, libero pellentesque dictum ullamcorper, purus arcu venenatis ante, a eleifend lorem nisi a mi. Quisque pretium enim id sagittis vulputate. Suspendisse finibus magna quis enim finibus, gravida euismod ex fermentum. Donec sollicitudin mauris sed odio dapibus tincidunt. Proin feugiat, magna et fermentum dapibus, lacus dui tincidunt sapien, et fringilla velit nisl non mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque in feugiat lectus. Proin venenatis pulvinar lorem, ut consequat dolor. Nunc sit amet velit sem. Fusce dictum hendrerit massa, sit amet dapibus velit vehicula ut. Maecenas sed nulla ultricies, consectetur augue eget, mollis nunc. Donec quis est venenatis, dignissim velit sed, mollis felis. Suspendisse id eros non dui interdum tincidunt. Cras nisl nunc, accumsan quis pretium quis, porttitor et elit. Integer gravida ac leo a eleifend. Fusce in posuere quam. Nunc elementum urna fringilla quam euismod, nec ultricies nunc facilisis. Morbi rutrum blandit magna, sollicitudin ullamcorper enim malesuada vitae. Aliquam pellentesque, leo a ultrices cursus, orci urna dapibus lorem, nec convallis massa metus in nisi. Nulla vel odio eu urna pellentesque mattis id a odio. Duis facilisis lacus erat, id dapibus dui laoreet eu. Pellentesque malesuada quam magna, a vehicula felis hendrerit quis. Aliquam lacinia vitae libero ac lacinia. Integer in elit orci. Donec nec augue feugiat, vulputate turpis non, mattis tellus. Nam vitae fermentum odio. Vestibulum accumsan rhoncus tellus, eget hendrerit augue. Vestibulum ut volutpat felis. Maecenas blandit laoreet nunc in tempus. Phasellus et rhoncus massa. Nunc varius turpis quis elit iaculis, vitae ornare nibh tincidunt. In at velit vel enim posuere iaculis et ac massa. Sed non nulla eget elit volutpat tempus. Phasellus vel massa metus. Nam vestibulum urna mi, vitae blandit nisl imperdiet nec. Sed auctor, lacus at molestie dapibus, nulla nisl pretium augue, ut faucibus leo felis ac mi. Nullam eget lacus metus. Nunc imperdiet risus metus, et vehicula nulla gravida ut. Sed faucibus lacus vel nibh tristique fermentum. Sed id iaculis nisl. Pellentesque quis nulla ullamcorper lacus molestie bibendum quis non odio. Ut neque mauris, mollis at auctor ac, cursus vitae urna. Nunc in erat et purus volutpat luctus eget eu metus. Fusce consequat, lectus ut scelerisque lacinia, enim diam tempor odio, ac hendrerit erat eros ac ipsum. Praesent pharetra felis non finibus dignissim. Quisque ullamcorper, dui sit amet dapibus dignissim, enim elit semper mauris, quis fringilla sapien felis nec nisl. Vestibulum sed viverra justo. Phasellus quis tempus lorem, vitae aliquam metus. In faucibus eleifend nisi, ac rhoncus velit dignissim eget. Mauris at cursus dolor. Nam ac leo urna. Proin varius facilisis tellus tristique faucibus. Nam fermentum ac enim non cursus. Sed mattis non enim sit amet euismod. Vivamus vitae egestas enim, pulvinar iaculis tellus. Donec condimentum non dui et tempor. Sed sit amet massa congue, hendrerit felis quis, tempor mi. Nam ornare dui sit amet nisl tempor, eu commodo erat rhoncus. Ut non aliquet libero. Maecenas tempus, massa quis congue semper, lacus libero gravida neque, id auctor velit dolor nec quam. Sed egestas tincidunt urna sit amet consectetur. Nam consequat orci lobortis tellus aliquam interdum. Suspendisse accumsan molestie urna id blandit. Vivamus hendrerit ex sapien, a varius ligula sagittis ac. Duis a massa sodales ex pharetra commodo at non dui. Donec aliquam nec erat in tempor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus et neque sed diam bibendum iaculis vel efficitur velit. Etiam sagittis in dui lobortis accumsan. Maecenas consectetur, enim nec tincidunt hendrerit, enim lacus sodales nibh, at blandit lectus elit sed nisi. Ut finibus eget justo ac tristique. Quisque placerat, nisi a euismod condimentum, velit tortor blandit est, sit amet hendrerit nisl eros a dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse eleifend risus quis turpis maximus, et volutpat quam bibendum. Ut cursus interdum leo vel pulvinar. Nulla id accumsan erat. Aliquam sodales mattis ipsum in congue. Praesent gravida massa id semper pharetra. Integer aliquam mauris non ullamcorper pellentesque. Aliquam eros velit, gravida sed dapibus id, finibus nec lectus. Pellentesque finibus mauris sed eleifend posuere. Curabitur faucibus et dolor sed tempor. Ut congue justo non nulla fringilla, in vehicula turpis tincidunt. Aliquam pretium mi a elit auctor, non ultricies justo pulvinar. Nullam sodales vehicula odio, ut eleifend ipsum laoreet sit amet. Nunc eget placerat ante. Praesent eros tellus, laoreet a purus nec, iaculis placerat justo. Cras aliquam velit vitae urna iaculis commodo. Nunc nisl odio, bibendum sed mi quis, suscipit dignissim lorem. Duis at tellus metus. Mauris sodales nisl eget nisl mollis elementum. Vestibulum dignissim viverra lacinia. Proin vitae sapien massa. Cras quis sapien sodales, dictum urna consequat, varius diam. Sed rhoncus vulputate enim feugiat ullamcorper. Sed ligula mauris, vestibulum ut erat eu, tempor imperdiet ante. Etiam quam massa, tempor eu sem semper, rhoncus viverra lacus. Suspendisse ultrices metus in sem ultrices ultrices. Curabitur et elit ligula. Pellentesque a placerat erat. Morbi scelerisque lobortis tellus, a feugiat dolor dignissim vitae. Quisque facilisis odio sem, ac facilisis velit sagittis nec. Morbi efficitur nunc id est viverra, eu maximus est efficitur. Cras feugiat nunc ac purus fringilla, et dictum urna vehicula. Curabitur vestibulum mollis sagittis. Etiam tincidunt turpis vitae mi porttitor, in vestibulum mauris sodales. Donec vel elit nulla. Curabitur sagittis augue egestas, pulvinar elit ac, vehicula orci. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus semper risus tempus, ultricies ligula sed, lacinia dui. Donec ullamcorper, magna a commodo vulputate, sem ligula molestie augue, at egestas quam massa eu felis. Sed tempus dictum tellus a tempus. Ut pharetra tellus tincidunt nisi porttitor, vitae laoreet leo laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam eget aliquam ligula. Fusce a vestibulum neque. Pellentesque a erat vehicula, interdum eros vulputate, rhoncus tortor. Duis quis suscipit mi. Nam eleifend, eros quis bibendum tincidunt, mi nisi ultrices elit, nec ultrices lacus sem quis nisi. Integer vulputate ultricies orci at viverra. In vitae faucibus massa. Sed laoreet sed leo at lobortis. Quisque ut ultrices mauris. Pellentesque sed tristique elit. Quisque sit amet enim a libero euismod fermentum. Proin ut dignissim felis. Praesent aliquam magna ut posuere malesuada. In eget velit in turpis auctor fermentum faucibus vel dolor. Phasellus enim eros, consequat quis ipsum quis, pellentesque consequat dolor. Sed tortor ligula, sollicitudin eu malesuada in, ullamcorper a odio. Sed rutrum, massa et viverra volutpat, orci justo elementum enim, vel vulputate ipsum sapien at libero. Ut facilisis, dolor et hendrerit fringilla, arcu diam congue enim, eget pulvinar lectus augue a urna. Ut semper facilisis mauris et posuere. Aenean in eleifend dui. Donec gravida, turpis eget posuere accumsan, neque lacus semper orci, a ornare dolor neque et nunc. Maecenas at lacus sagittis lectus rutrum vestibulum. Aenean efficitur ipsum vel sagittis fringilla. Vestibulum sollicitudin elit id nunc ullamcorper sodales. Etiam auctor auctor quam, at porttitor arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam eget elementum dui. Suspendisse erat ipsum, sagittis in tempus non, pulvinar ut augue. Morbi sem libero, ornare non feugiat in, sagittis in odio. Morbi mollis placerat felis. Suspendisse facilisis quis enim ac vulputate. Nunc ut arcu nec nibh volutpat feugiat. Maecenas vel arcu volutpat nibh commodo consequat quis a augue. Proin imperdiet semper velit non tempus. Maecenas vitae libero eu turpis placerat tempor. Nulla maximus elit id enim aliquam, nec tempus lectus porttitor. Duis ultricies arcu purus, ac finibus lacus lacinia gravida. Nunc vel quam mattis, dictum massa vitae, tincidunt lectus. Integer dignissim dolor tortor, nec bibendum dui malesuada et. Cras cursus, turpis vel pretium vehicula, nisl ante congue felis, at pulvinar massa nulla sed odio. Integer facilisis lectus metus, vel tempus risus mattis at. Ut vulputate consequat nunc, ac venenatis augue semper ac. Vestibulum non suscipit orci, nec efficitur urna. Pellentesque porttitor vitae lorem vitae porttitor. Nunc vel massa elit. Integer sapien nulla, pharetra a egestas ut, euismod bibendum massa. Duis tempor lorem vel eros venenatis, ac pellentesque purus venenatis. Ut velit ex, posuere vitae enim quis, porttitor hendrerit nulla. Fusce vulputate consequat dui et placerat. Integer vitae viverra magna, vel iaculis diam. Nullam suscipit ex id porta condimentum. Ut quis sapien ut augue imperdiet pretium vitae eu magna. Etiam vulputate vestibulum pretium. Nulla facilisi. Donec congue tristique ligula at tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at sem eros. Maecenas id sapien eget nisi vestibulum tincidunt vel quis lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce porttitor sem sollicitudin ipsum aliquet porttitor. Fusce vel elit bibendum, fermentum neque condimentum, maximus elit. Nunc interdum, lectus non euismod eleifend, velit felis varius purus, in consectetur urna massa in augue. Proin viverra arcu at nunc tincidunt, ut facilisis ante ultricies. Nulla eget ultrices tortor. Aenean tristique volutpat elit, sed congue ex facilisis sed. Proin lacus metus, sodales at scelerisque at, rutrum at libero. Fusce mauris nibh, sollicitudin faucibus neque lobortis, mollis mollis ex. Nam varius pellentesque enim, eu posuere ligula accumsan sit amet. Mauris pharetra tellus ut odio pharetra, at cursus metus rutrum. Fusce id commodo turpis, eget maximus purus. Nullam ante elit, porttitor at consequat id, sodales varius tortor. Phasellus ut cursus nulla, et pharetra leo. Ut ut ultricies lorem. Donec id enim consequat ex viverra mattis non ac augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas sollicitudin, neque vel blandit condimentum, ligula elit fermentum nunc, sollicitudin facilisis risus urna et diam. Vestibulum in diam eget tortor congue commodo sed id neque. Praesent in libero vel nunc sagittis euismod. In ut libero dui. Sed porttitor risus eu elementum finibus. Vivamus nulla est, malesuada vel imperdiet eu, porta a massa. Fusce nec imperdiet augue. Etiam interdum ac sapien eget convallis. Duis tincidunt ante at nisi malesuada, sed ultrices nibh bibendum. Mauris euismod tempor rutrum. Donec sit amet eros ipsum. Donec eget massa at mi fermentum luctus ut vel libero. Morbi malesuada libero sit amet aliquet congue. Maecenas sagittis interdum nisi at dapibus. Duis vitae quam vitae mauris imperdiet rhoncus porta eu purus. Nullam est odio, imperdiet a odio ac, eleifend lobortis erat. Nullam eu aliquam urna, in suscipit ante. Ut gravida ex non laoreet porttitor. Pellentesque dictum ex at sagittis vestibulum. Suspendisse tincidunt nibh id est tincidunt facilisis. Pellentesque tortor risus, commodo ac porta sed, lobortis eu ligula. Sed augue arcu, tempor posuere venenatis sit amet, placerat in diam. In neque erat, sollicitudin vel nisl ut, lobortis venenatis lacus. Praesent vel cursus quam, non vestibulum mi. Ut condimentum lobortis velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut ut consequat justo, sed tincidunt augue. Ut aliquet nibh non ipsum posuere lacinia. Fusce laoreet metus massa, non consequat ipsum fringilla ut. Etiam vel velit quis dolor lobortis porta. Sed ullamcorper arcu vitae rutrum euismod. Suspendisse massa leo, interdum eget porttitor et, lacinia eget massa. Proin euismod purus in ullamcorper porta. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus elit ipsum, dignissim ac ullamcorper eget, rutrum eget velit. Sed elementum eu turpis id fermentum. Sed sollicitudin, lectus in blandit finibus, augue diam condimentum ante, id sagittis lectus nulla interdum libero. Maecenas mattis ipsum id tincidunt consequat. Praesent dui lectus, pellentesque vel interdum in, posuere ut lacus. Duis faucibus at ex non tincidunt. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer nibh nisl, bibendum at tempus quis, rutrum quis tellus. Ut ut interdum justo, in sodales ex. Pellentesque sit amet congue ex. Cras vitae dolor efficitur, tincidunt tellus vitae, congue orci. Integer mollis sollicitudin ultrices. Mauris non lobortis quam. Morbi mollis sagittis lacinia. Aenean id pellentesque enim, sed cursus nunc. Curabitur dignissim, nunc ac luctus tempor, erat nisi aliquam justo, sed auctor mauris lectus in turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum condimentum felis eu nulla vehicula, a placerat magna dapibus. Cras quis molestie est. Quisque hendrerit euismod lacus, sit amet scelerisque eros pulvinar eu. Nam fringilla ipsum ac nisl facilisis mollis. Vivamus pretium elit ac suscipit gravida. Suspendisse consequat pharetra tincidunt. Nulla ut odio eget purus pellentesque molestie. Duis pretium leo vitae ipsum condimentum, eget commodo orci maximus. Donec sed nunc sit amet ex consequat maximus ac nec arcu. Aliquam et volutpat erat, eget vestibulum lacus. Donec lacinia accumsan sapien vel condimentum. Nam scelerisque semper lectus, eu luctus velit gravida a. Sed fringilla laoreet odio, in tincidunt dui interdum at. Praesent laoreet lorem non nunc ultrices egestas. Vestibulum hendrerit neque et quam tempus vehicula. Nunc ex purus, lacinia vel tincidunt nec, vestibulum sed nulla. Nam ac fermentum orci, sit amet porttitor turpis. Integer nec est vestibulum, porttitor massa id, dictum sapien. Donec sed ex porta, bibendum enim sit amet, efficitur metus. Aliquam elementum magna a dui ullamcorper dictum. Phasellus dignissim lobortis mauris eu dapibus. Ut egestas eros a tincidunt aliquam. Etiam dapibus ipsum turpis, sed viverra eros elementum nec. Suspendisse auctor leo orci, a pharetra leo porttitor ac. Curabitur laoreet dolor eget sem ullamcorper, ut semper felis feugiat. Etiam gravida eros quis diam hendrerit venenatis. Quisque hendrerit laoreet felis nec sodales. Curabitur vel arcu tempus risus fermentum varius at ut mauris. Integer ultricies pellentesque lobortis. Aenean finibus velit sagittis eleifend ultricies. Fusce elementum orci vitae mauris gravida, quis cursus dui posuere. Duis ligula elit, varius vel risus nec, accumsan dapibus orci. Curabitur eros odio, eleifend ac condimentum nec, fermentum in nibh. Curabitur tristique purus quis sapien rhoncus, eget placerat dui malesuada. Vivamus facilisis euismod libero, et mattis massa commodo sit amet. Proin varius aliquet nisl. Aenean nec turpis pharetra, faucibus mauris fringilla, commodo dui. Vestibulum ante massa, pellentesque fringilla lobortis sagittis, mattis sed nisi. Suspendisse fringilla feugiat felis, sed tincidunt quam porttitor non. Vestibulum diam turpis, dapibus cursus quam eu, accumsan viverra mi. Sed consequat nibh at purus vestibulum suscipit. Nunc vestibulum, justo vestibulum tempor ornare, ligula mauris vestibulum neque, at sagittis lectus velit at nisl. Curabitur cursus euismod tortor, eget pharetra massa euismod nec. Nullam vitae suscipit turpis, imperdiet luctus ante. Fusce aliquam, mauris eget iaculis vulputate, magna dolor mollis neque, hendrerit ultrices tellus mauris id sapien. Fusce sed sodales sapien, ut iaculis augue. Curabitur ac diam sit amet velit porttitor tristique. Mauris metus elit, vestibulum sit amet blandit consequat, mattis non nulla. Sed tristique, neque eget dapibus scelerisque, risus est blandit magna, a commodo orci turpis rutrum magna. Duis id posuere odio. Donec porttitor, nunc ut faucibus ornare, neque ex tincidunt nulla, at molestie erat turpis at ligula. Mauris nunc quam, elementum in lorem ac, hendrerit tempus elit. Phasellus venenatis nisl non sem posuere semper. Curabitur in justo id purus vehicula varius eget eget nunc. Proin eget ultrices leo. Nullam in efficitur felis. Pellentesque risus orci, bibendum eget accumsan sit amet, fringilla et nibh. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce finibus lorem nec mi rutrum, quis vulputate orci malesuada. Ut laoreet, justo eget malesuada varius, nulla felis bibendum erat, at tincidunt quam tellus id eros. Pellentesque ac tellus rutrum, accumsan sem at, iaculis libero. Fusce in magna est. Nunc velit ante, imperdiet sit amet mi nec, tincidunt viverra est. Morbi tellus dolor, ultricies a sapien id, scelerisque interdum urna. Vivamus quis purus augue. Duis risus sem, suscipit quis varius eget, malesuada ut nulla. Nunc imperdiet diam elementum lorem egestas egestas. Morbi bibendum tortor in vehicula egestas. Vivamus ac velit eu nibh varius egestas mollis congue dolor. Mauris accumsan, dolor eget facilisis pellentesque, purus lorem condimentum turpis, eget placerat lectus risus ut enim. Mauris lacinia mattis convallis. Maecenas varius nisl sed sapien scelerisque porttitor. Proin vitae ullamcorper nulla, eget placerat tellus. Maecenas vitae varius arcu, non sagittis turpis. Pellentesque consectetur mauris sem, a maximus felis efficitur non. Suspendisse blandit placerat sem vel facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse convallis ut nisi quis fermentum. Curabitur nec lorem a risus laoreet porta. Etiam volutpat nunc eu scelerisque pellentesque. Curabitur tristique dolor dignissim, faucibus libero ut, scelerisque urna. Proin tempus nibh id sollicitudin tincidunt. Integer lobortis a massa et lobortis. Donec posuere lacus sit amet erat dictum hendrerit. Aenean sed pellentesque leo, vitae dignissim lectus. Proin euismod risus velit. Aenean id magna vitae lacus posuere rutrum eleifend non mauris. Nulla egestas, nisi a placerat aliquet, felis tortor aliquet velit, quis feugiat erat ipsum in arcu. Praesent tristique lectus sapien, ac consequat mauris lobortis vitae. In sit amet elit sapien. Nam posuere commodo elit vitae venenatis. Duis a auctor nibh. Curabitur in dui lorem. Fusce eu hendrerit metus. Vestibulum quis rhoncus nisl. Donec sit amet molestie dui. Suspendisse at malesuada lacus, sed mattis massa. Quisque a urna id diam semper fringilla sit amet in orci. Etiam lorem mi, facilisis ultrices nulla sed, mollis vehicula eros. Donec et dictum turpis. Vivamus nec mauris semper, posuere lorem eget, varius tellus. Vivamus eget leo luctus, egestas ex a, laoreet ipsum. Praesent non gravida nisi. Sed consectetur, risus nec consectetur fringilla, est justo pulvinar mauris, a gravida ex libero a mauris. Nunc commodo, augue sed pretium pulvinar, ipsum ipsum efficitur dui, vitae hendrerit sem neque at turpis. In et lorem id nisl finibus rhoncus. Sed nec varius libero. Cras lobortis, nibh in ornare scelerisque, quam nisi pharetra nibh, ut finibus diam nulla hendrerit nisl. Morbi sit amet justo mattis, lacinia leo et, mattis arcu. Maecenas orci lorem, molestie a consectetur sollicitudin, suscipit vitae tellus. Sed in urna quis augue accumsan placerat. Vivamus viverra lectus nec risus scelerisque efficitur. Fusce ac orci quis enim fermentum imperdiet sed eget justo. Cras mollis urna purus, quis luctus nisi rhoncus nec. Maecenas sagittis lectus id rutrum fermentum. Proin ut hendrerit massa. In in turpis ut enim convallis molestie sed in diam. Morbi venenatis mauris neque, ut efficitur metus dictum at. In at odio elementum nunc accumsan mollis et eu felis. Proin ac dolor id nulla blandit eleifend nec a ante. Suspendisse potenti. Donec nec vehicula libero. Mauris turpis arcu, luctus nec vestibulum congue, sodales et odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla vel tempor lorem. Proin nibh nunc, facilisis sed bibendum laoreet, pellentesque ut risus. Mauris sodales pulvinar ultrices. Maecenas viverra velit orci, lobortis pulvinar ipsum iaculis eu. Ut viverra commodo justo ac consectetur. Donec quis elit dui. Aliquam sed pellentesque purus. Vestibulum vitae enim quis nulla auctor varius. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper tortor turpis, eget fringilla nunc molestie in. Nulla facilisi. Etiam ultricies rhoncus purus, condimentum ultrices velit maximus aliquet. Praesent accumsan sem lorem, ut luctus sem mattis sit amet. Morbi vel pretium sem, vitae porttitor nibh. Nullam condimentum ut odio ut maximus. Sed nec mauris vitae felis interdum eleifend. Nulla eros leo, placerat vel congue vel, feugiat nec ex. Praesent sed sollicitudin felis, id euismod nulla. Vestibulum tempus magna vitae felis suscipit, id finibus est viverra. In vitae mattis urna, quis ultrices nisi. Morbi vel elit ut erat facilisis faucibus vel in diam. Phasellus non euismod libero. Donec augue lacus, elementum sed pretium ut, eleifend ut neque. Duis id est tellus. Donec malesuada eu quam at sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget metus mi. Sed eu est ultrices, malesuada felis vitae, aliquam eros. Aliquam at aliquet dui. Vivamus ornare mi sit amet tristique tempus. Maecenas sed mi mauris. Integer in risus sed erat rutrum dapibus. Ut lobortis sagittis leo non pharetra. Proin consequat volutpat molestie. Morbi hendrerit ligula non odio varius iaculis. Nulla pharetra leo libero, in sodales nunc bibendum vitae. Curabitur mattis tincidunt pulvinar. Suspendisse blandit leo arcu, in mattis massa pretium eu. Donec hendrerit urna libero, sed dictum erat mollis non. Pellentesque lacus libero, tempus euismod consequat non, faucibus a dolor. Vestibulum consequat sapien luctus sem consectetur pulvinar. Phasellus auctor, nisi vitae volutpat viverra, dui nibh scelerisque arcu, ac gravida nulla massa ut libero. Pellentesque placerat nunc non pharetra ultrices. Duis elit lacus, auctor venenatis lorem a, rutrum hendrerit libero. Donec tellus enim, aliquet in tellus vel, sollicitudin feugiat erat. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur porta turpis eget nulla tincidunt, ut cursus urna ornare. In tristique ornare urna, eget maximus justo euismod ac. Sed porta ultricies dui, nec tincidunt nunc blandit quis. Suspendisse rutrum nisl nec euismod imperdiet. Etiam aliquam, diam sed dapibus bibendum, tortor sem laoreet ante, sit amet sollicitudin est justo eu sem.
 
</main>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, thank you.  Turned out I had another `html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100vw; }` which i forgot to include in the question, which was also affecting the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Great please mark the answer so that everyone will know the problem has been solved. Find a tick mark on left side of answer just click on it. 
Thanks.