# Fixed width layout with one child spanning full screen width

Tags: css

Can I create a layout like on the picture below, while setting the fixed width only on the parent container?  I also cannot use `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` on *Full screen width child*, as I cannot remove it from the flow, because it's size is dynamic.

I can't change the markup.

The only solution I can think of is setting the fixed width on every *Fixed-width child* separately, but as I have a lot of them, that's not the most comfortable solution - means adding a class for every child that I add into the parent container.

[image: Desired layout]

Here is an example markup you can post a solution to.

*HTML*

```
<div class="fixed-width-container">
  <div class="regular-child"></div>
  <div class="full-screen-width-child"></div>
  <div class="regular-child"></div>
  <div class="regular-child"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.fixed-width-container {
  width: <some-fixed-width>;
}
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: Essentially, **unless** the full width element is for styling only...you cannot do this with CSS alone without changing the HTML given the constraints you have imposed.

Comment: @Paulie_D: That's what I thought, but wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something. Thanks.

BTW I think CSS Grid would allow doing that, but we all know how poor support it has so far.

Comment: You could perhaps wrap those in 2 different containers - 1 for the ones above full width div & the other for ones below it. That's the only way I can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give a try to the flex layout : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.fixed-width-container {
  width: 400px;/* any width set */
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixed-width-container>div {
  height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.full-screen-width-child {
  width: 99vw;/* 100vw is fine too */
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-container">
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
  <div class="full-screen-width-child">Full screen width child with dynamic contents</div>
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
</div>
```

[codepen to test and play with](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZrNXm)

Comment: Works indeed! Just what I was looking for. Thanks! I made a pen to experiment with your solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZrNXm . You can link it to you answer; maybe someone will find it helpful

Comment: Unfortunately `width: 100vw;` introduces another problem - vertical scrollbar (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one#23367686). But that answer passess all the criteria of the question, so I leave it accepted.

Comment: Today I figured out that setting `html { overflow-y: scroll; }` fixes the issue with scrollbar. I propose adding that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an attempt, and probably not a very good one. But maybe it will spawn some more sophisticated solutions by others, or even yourself.

---

**Idea:** negative margins for the full-width child.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-width-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: LightYellow;
}

.regular-child,
.full-screen-width-child {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  background: LightBlue;
}

.full-screen-width-child {
  margin-left: -24%;
  margin-right: -24%;
  background: LightGreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-container">
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
  <div class="full-screen-width-child">Full screen width child with dynamic contents</div>
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
  <div class="regular-child">Fixed-width child</div>
</div>
```

The problematic part here is the dimension of the negative margins. If you use `%`, it will relate to the `width` of the `fixed-width-container`. Here, I chose `width: 70%` for it. Given a body width of `625px` (as is the case for the Stack Snippet preview) and a margin of `-24%`, that would give a negative margin of `625px * 0.7 * 0.24 = 105px`. I'm not sure what's the best approach of making this work for any configuration.