# Why 100vw + 100vh gives horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs `1 x 100%` and `2 x 100vw`.

Then if I set 100vh height to 100vw div (the black one) - I will get overflow-x and will get *horizontal* scroll.

Why is this happening? As per my understanding in this case `100vw` should be equal to `100%` as they're inside the `body` which doesn't have any margin/padding and has `box-sizing: border-box`.
[image]

```js
show100vhDiv = function() {
  document.querySelector('.height-100vh').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Lato;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.test {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}

.width-100vw {
  background: salmon;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.height-100vh {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
  background: mediumvioletred;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show100vhDiv()">Toggle 100vh x 100vw element</button>
<div class="test width-100vw">100vw</div>
<div class="test width-100">100%</div>
<div class="test width-100vw height-100vh">100vh x 100vw</div>
```

Comment: Just looks like margin on the `body`, have you tried adding `margin: 0;` to `body`?

Comment: Because 100VW includes space set aside for scrollbars. 100% does not.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo it has `* {margin: 0, padding: 0}`

Comment: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Jan/0200.html

Comment: @Paulie_D the question that you mendioned when marked as duplicate still not gives clear answer, will check this html

Comment: I beg to diiffer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367686/2802040