# horizontal scroll bar at larger viewports

Tags: html, css

I have a site that is using bootstrap and some custom css. I have a css class called "full-width" design to escape the parent bootstrap "container" in order to get the background color to extend the entire width of the screen. I just noticed that I have a horizontal scrollbar on desktop. I have narrowed it down to the "full-width" class but I cannot figure out how to fix it. It has been fin up until recently.

Staging site: https://staging.warsaw.church

I really appreciate and help!

Comment: You should add code to reproduce this issue. That aside, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one/23367686

Answer (score 2):

Fix this part of the css it worked for me

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    full-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the horizontal scroll bar but now the navbar and footer do not extend to the edge.