# Why aren't my elements centered in my flex container?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I'm building the website for the web development company I just registered (which is also intended to be part of my portfolio for job applications) and on my portfolio page, I'm adding a visual list of websites that I've completed for clients, and I'm using `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to for the wrapper, but they don't seem to be perfectly aligned, the gap on the left is bigger than the gap on the right, and it's more prominent in a mobile view:

[image]

Here are the `styled-components` I'm using below the header:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fadeInUp } from 'react-animations';

export const PortfolioContainer = styled.div`
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 110px;
`

export const PortfolioHeader = styled.h1`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color:  ${props => props.txtColor};
`

export const PortfolioWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    padding-top: 15px;
`

export const PortfolioLinkWrap = styled.div`
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    background: ${props => props.background};
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: ${props => `${props.num/2}s`} ${keyframes `${fadeInUp}`};
    margin-bottom: 10px;
`

export const PortfolioLinkImg = styled.img`
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 15px;
`

export const PortfolioLink = styled(Link)`
    color: ${props => props.txtcolor};
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 15px;

    &:hover {
        color: ${props => props.txthovercolor};
        background: ${props => props.hoverbackground};
        transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
`
```

And here is the `React` component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import content from './content.js'
import {
    PortfolioContainer,
    PortfolioLinkWrap,
    PortfolioHeader,
    PortfolioWrapper,
    PortfolioLink,
    PortfolioLinkImg,
} from "./PortfolioElements";

const Portfolio = ({
    highlightTxtColor,
    elementBg,
    elementBg2,
    siteText
}) => {
  return (
    <PortfolioContainer>
        <PortfolioHeader txtColor={highlightTxtColor}>
            Portfolio
        </PortfolioHeader>
        <PortfolioWrapper>
            {content.map((e,i) => (
                <PortfolioLinkWrap 
                    key={e.id} 
                    background={elementBg2}
                    num={i+1}
                >
                    <PortfolioLink 
                        to={e.link}
                        target='_blank'
                        txtcolor={siteText}
                        txthovercolor={highlightTxtColor}
                        hoverbackground={elementBg}
                    >
                    <PortfolioLinkImg
                        src={e.img}
                    />
                        {e.text}
                    </PortfolioLink>
                </PortfolioLinkWrap>
            ))}
        </PortfolioWrapper>
    </PortfolioContainer>
  )
}

export default Portfolio
```

UPDATE: I figured out that it's because the `PortfolioContainer` element is wider than the screen. However it's set to `width: 100vw;` so I'm not sure why that is. I tried setting both the header and the `PortfolioWrap` element do `display: none;` to make sure neither of those were affecting it, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [100vw causing horizontal overflow, but only if more than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the elements are centered in flex container, But `PortfoloioContainer`'s width is wider than the screen.

Add `max-width:100%` to your `PortfoloioContainer`. This will fix the issue.

Hope it helps!